# Getting Bus error: 10 when looping through a string array

Tags: c

I initialized 2 arrays of strings which I believe is `{NULL, NULL, NULL}` I am trying to iterate through the array `variableName` and check is a certain string exists e.g. "hello". It doesn't exist in this case so I expect it to print `"not found"` but instead I get a Bus error: 10

```
char variableName[3][20];
char variableValue[3][20];

void addVar(char name[], char value[]) {

    if (varDeclared(name, variableName) == 1) {

        printf("exists");
        int index = getIndex(name, variableName);
        changeVal(value, variableValue, index);

    }
    else {
        printf("not found");
    }
}

int varDeclared(char name[], char variableName[][20]) {

    int i = 0;

    while(variableName[i]) {
        if (strcmp(name, variableName[i]) == 0) {
            return 1;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int getIndex(char name[], char variableName[][20]) {

    int i = 0;

    while(variableName[i]) {
        if (strcmp(name, variableName[i]) == 0) {
            return i;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a `main()` function that shows your code in action & crashing?

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Also consider to check this list https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: @Stefan You better ask for a [mcve]. To do that write `[mcve]` in your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare

```
char variableName[3][20];
char variableValue[3][20];
```

It is not that `variableName[0]`, `variableName[1]`, `variableName[2]` will be holding `NULL`. Instead they will be holding respective row address.

Thus your check like below,

```
 while(variableName[i]) {
    .....
    i++;
 }
```

Will always return true and you access out of bound.

---

Change it as below

```
while(variableName[i][0] != '\0') //Loop until empty string.
```

or declare array of pointers.

```
 char *variableName[3] = {NULL,NULL,NULL};
 char *variableValue[3] = {NULL,NULL,NULL};
```

Make sure you allocate memory before dereferencing.